# Waiting for first of multiple things concurrently

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

If I wanted to simultaneously...

- Write to a socket that will start a long-running remote task and listen for the eventual response
- Regularly do a high-level heartbeat (as compared to keep-alive) on said socket

  - For example, at regular intervals, send "ping" and expect "pong" within some time interval, otherwise shut down the socket
- Listen for button-clicks

  - These may cancel the current operation on the socket, which requires letting the remote server know

To look at it another way, if you're familiar with socket select, I'm looking for something similar to that, but that I could use to wait for the socket or the GUI; whichever returns first.

I feel like maybe what I'm looking for is simply some form of queue, but I'd like to know if there's something more appropriate.

What should I use to try to get results from the first of multiple threads without polling?

Comment: The `Selector` class, maybe?

Comment: Although the `Selector` class has `select`, I don't think that's what I'm after, as the things I want to select on would have to be subclasses of `SelectableChannel`, which they are not.

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want to put a read timeout? Multiplexing on the socket is bound to result in some ugly code, especially if you don't go the `NIO/Selector` route.

Comment: I don't think the socket responses will be that hard to deal with. Parse the JSON, grab the response type key, and call a method based on that. My question is primarily asking about waiting on *either* a click from the GUI or a response from the socket without polling. I'm feeling more and more like a `BlockingQueue` is what I'm looking for.